# how to pay Gas fees by the claimer's address

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, ether, metamask

I have a token erc20 .. and I created a method to buy this token.. and I want him to pay the GAS fees from his account using the metamask wallet

and this is my code ..

```
interface IERC20 {
    
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract BuyTokens {
    IERC20 token;

    function withdraw(address beneficiary) public {

        uint256 value = balanceOf(_admin).mul(5).div(100);
        require(balanceOf(_admin) > value);
        token.transfer(beneficiary, value);
    }

}
```

plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gas fees are by default always paid by the account that signed the Ethereum transaction (in your case probably in most cases the account that calls your contract)

An alternative to this would be adding support for [OpenGSN](https://docs.opengsn.org/)

Comment: Is my code correct?

Comment: Actually didn't check :D Looking at your contract I have some questions: What is `_admin`? How do you wand to sell the token (e.g. for ETH)? Also you are asking multiple questions at once. I would recommend to split them. I only answered the fee related part, as this was the one from the title.